How to convert Python Dictionary to simple String values by removing duplicates
I am trying to convert a list of dictionaries to a simple comma-separated string with duplicate keys removed.
here is my dictionary
"Message": [
    {
        "table_name": "sec_sp",
        "column_name": "field_1"
    },
    {
        "table_name": "sec_sp",
        "column_name": "field_2"
    },
    {
        "table_name": "sec_si",
        "column_name": "field_3"
    },
    {
        "table_name": "sec_si",
        "column_name": "field_4"
    },
    {
        "table_name": "sec_sp",
        "column_name": "field_5"
    },
    {
        "table_name": "sec_sc",
        "column_name": "field_6"
    },
    {
        "table_name": "sec_sc",
        "column_name": "field_7"
    }
]

I wanted to convert it to below strings.
sp_list = "field_1,field_2,field_5"
si_list = "field_3,field_4"
sc_list = "field_6,field_7"

I tried separating out to keys and values using below code however not able to remove dupes.
for key, value in Message.items():


That's not a dictionary. That is a list of dictionaries.

And what you have shown is not a real attempt.

Since the data format is a list and not directly a dictionary, you'd iterate through the list, collect items into separate lists based on the table_name, and then join those lists into strings.
message = [
    {"table_name": "sec_sp", "column_name": "field_1"},
    {"table_name": "sec_sp", "column_name": "field_2"},
    {"table_name": "sec_si", "column_name": "field_3"},
    {"table_name": "sec_si", "column_name": "field_4"},
    {"table_name": "sec_sp", "column_name": "field_5"},
    {"table_name": "sec_sc", "column_name": "field_6"},
    {"table_name": "sec_sc", "column_name": "field_7"}
]

# Using a dictionary to collect column names for each table
columns_by_table = {}

# Iterate over each entry in the message
for entry in message:
    table = entry["table_name"]
    column = entry["column_name"]
    if table not in columns_by_table:
        columns_by_table[table] = []
    # Add the column name to the corresponding table's list
    columns_by_table[table].append(column)

sp_list = ",".join(columns_by_table.get("sec_sp", []))
si_list = ",".join(columns_by_table.get("sec_si", []))
sc_list = ",".join(columns_by_table.get("sec_sc", []))

print(f"sp_list = \"{sp_list}\"")
print(f"si_list = \"{si_list}\"")
print(f"sc_list = \"{sc_list}\"")

I hope this will help you a little.

this is helpful

@Sachin Check out What to do when someone answers.

You could try using the set() function to remove duplicates of a list
after obtaining all posible columns for a table name.
inline_dict = {}
for message in your_data.get('Message'):
    inline_dict.update({message.get('table_name'): inline_dict.get(message.get('table_name'), []) + [message.get('column_name')]})

strings_dict = {}    
for k, v in inline_dict.items():
    strings_dict[k] = ','.join(list(set(v)))

after this you would end up with a dictionary with table_names as keys and the concatenated column names as the values.
